# How to check if libpng and png++ is installed

Tags: 14.04, png, libpng

How do I check if `png++` and `libpng` is installed in Ubuntu? I am trying to compile [this code](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/%7Edmcallester/SPS/index.html) and the readme says `libpng` and `png++` are required:

> ### SPS-Stereo: Slanted Plane Smoothing Stereo
>
> SPS-Stereo is a dense stereo method employing a slanted plane model. It jointly estimates a superpixel segmentation, boundry labels (such as occlusion boundaries), and a dense depth estimate from a pair of stereo images.
>
> **Citation**
>
> ```
> @inproceedings{Yamaguchi14,
> author = {Koichiro Yamaguchi and David McAllester and Raquel Urtasun},
> title = {Efficient Joint Segmentation, Occlusion Labeling, Stereo and Flow Estimation},
> booktitle = {ECCV},
> year = {2014}
> }
> ```
>
> #### Building SPS-Stereo
>
> 1. Prerequisites
>
>    - [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)
>    - [png++](http://www.nongnu.org/pngpp/)
> 2. Building
>
>    1. type 'cmake .'
>    2. type 'make'
>
> #### Usage of demo code
>
> First, download KITTI stereo/flow dataset from [KITTI Vision Benchmark Suite homepage](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_stereo_flow.php?benchmark=stereo) and extract it.
>
> Run SPS-Stereo
> `> ./spsstereo data_stereo_flow/training/image_0/000000_10.png data_stereo_flow/training/image_1/000000_10.png`

I have followed the instructions to install both, but I am getting an error:

```
/home/usr/spsstereo/spsstereo_main.cpp:22:25: fatal error: png++/png.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <png++/png.hpp>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/spsstereo.dir/spsstereo_main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/spsstereo.dir/all] Error 2
```

I'm guessing `png++` is not installed. How do I check?

Comment: In Ubuntu, the development headers and libraries are usually packaged separately from the runtime libraries: in this case you probably need `libpng++-dev`

Comment: Wow that has worked ! Program running smoothly now ! You linux experts are amazing

Answer (score 1):

Since the above [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806160/how-to-check-if-libpng-and-png-is-installed#comment1218080_806160) by [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) worked for me for the same error, I'm making it an answer so people can easily find it:

> In Ubuntu, the development headers and libraries are usually packaged separately from the runtime libraries: in this case you probably need `libpng++-dev`.